# Ext JS 4.0 cancel store load if proxy encounters exception

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, extjs

Can I somehow stop the .load() process when the proxy associated with a store encounters an exception, such as 404?

I'm using the Ajax proxy. There is an ['exception' event on the proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-event-exception), but I could not figure out what exactly to do in the callback.

Right now, the store tries to stuff the data into the model (using the mappings defined by me), even though there is no data, which results in ugly red error messages.

**UPDATE**

Maybe it would be better not to stop the load() process, but instead to handle the missing data in the thing (reader?) that actually converts the JSON to model  instances. The idea is to handle missing data gracefully. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a little tricky, especially if your store is tied to a dataviewer component.

The `load()` process will be halted once it reaches the `exception` event so I believe you have no control there.

You could manually populate data into the store using the `store.add()` when handling the Ajax's `exception` event,

```
ajax.on('exception', function () {
    // since exception was called, i'll have to input data myself.
    store.add({
        field1: 'value1', 
        field2: 'value2'
    });
});
```

My code is based on ExtJS 3 syntax and may vary with ExtJS 4's but the concept should be the same.

Comment: Marking as accepted, even though I "fixed" it by making the backend always provide nice responses.